# Function that sums all values in row by 100 and change zeros

Tags: python, numpy, math

here is something that I thought would be easier but is not (for me)...

I have some data as the one bellow:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'column1' : [0, 49, 50, 0, 100], 
    'column2' : [100, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'column3' : [0, 51, 50, 100, 0]
})
```

the output for my needs is better seen like this:

```
(0,100,0
49,0,51
50,0,50
0,0,100
100,0,0)
```

I need fix these values as none of then are zero and all rows sum to one. (column1 + column2 + column3 = 100)
ex:

```
(1,98,1
49,1,50
49,1,50
1,1,98
98,1,1)
```

I thought about some function that would identify the maximum or minimum column, like np.maximum() or np.minimum() but I can't solve for the cases like row 0, row 3 or row 4... Any help would be appreciate..

Comment: Hey, I just typed it that way to be easier to read. It's not to transpose the rows. I can't see how to transpose a 0,100,0 would turn to 1,98,1

Comment: Got it; my apologies.  Reopened.

Comment: Hey, I made a lot of attempts (a lot) that did not work and believed it could make the question harder to read. Next time I'll post with all the code. Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


data = pd.DataFrame({ 
'column1' : [0, 49, 50, 0, 100], 
'column2' : [100, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
'column3' : [0, 51, 50, 100, 0]
})

for row in data.values:  #data.values gets all rows of the df
    to_minus = list(row).count(0) #Get num of 0, subtract from max(row)

    for i in range(len(row)):
        elem = row[i]

        if elem == 0:  #If elem is 0 add 1 to elem
        row[i] += 1

        else:
            if row[i] == max(row): # If elem is max(row) subtract num of 0
               row[i] -= to_minus
               to_minus = 0         # Set to minus to 0 in case of duplicates
print(data)
```

Comment: Hey, tks a lot!, it got really clean! I'm quite new in programming and would take me really long to get to this! My code was getting giant and no solving my problem..

Comment: You are welcome, please upvote me and mark the question as answered :)